# How many permutations of the letters "DATACLASSRULES" but the letters "DATA" must stay together in any order. Repeated letters are not unique.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I've tried doing 10!4! ÷ 2!3!2! = 3628800. But I'm getting told I'm wrong. 4!÷2! for "DATA" multiplying to 10!÷2!3! for "CLASSRULES". What am I missing and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things missing in your answer.

First, where DATA will end up. (11 possiblilities)

Second, the fact that there is a third A. We'll consider them unique at first then divide the final answer by $6!$

Rearrange the letter DATA : $4!$

Rearrange CLASSRULES : $\dfrac{10!}{3!2!}$

Place DATA inside CLASSRULES : $11$

Rearrange the 3 A : $\div 3!$

Answer :
$$\frac{4!\times11\times10!}{3!\times2!\times3!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alain's solution is neat: here is an alternate way based on "building up" permutations with unmarked balls, which is often useful when the conventional method becomes difficult.

- First build up a block of $4,\;$ placing the balls one by one, so $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4 =24,\;\;$ bind into an unordered block representing letters DATA
- Then similarly place the remaining $10$ balls one by one, around the "DATA" block in $2\times 3\times\;\;...\;\;\times{11} = 11!$ ways
- Finally, adjust for repeats of $AAA,\, SSS,\, LL$

Thus $Ans= \Large\frac{24\times 11!}{3!3!2!}$